# How to use API key for google geocode requests (v3 javascript API)

Tags: maps, geocode, limits

I keep getting access denied when using my api key for geocode requests.  it works fine without the key but limits me to 2500/day.  Here's a sample lookup im using:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&sensor=false&address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA